# Me.Value doesn't work for text align expression - SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

There are number of fields in the report and i am trying to use the following expression for text align (so that i can copy across other fields) but it is not working and giving error message.

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Me.Value), "Center", "Right")
```

Error:

> The TextAlign expression for the paragraph ‘MyPO.Paragraphs[0]’
>   contains "Me.Value". "Me.Value" is not valid in the context of a
>   paragraph.

I can use `"Fields!MyPO.Value"` instead of using `"Me.Value"` but i will have to write a separate expression for each field.

I am justing wondering if this is still a Bug in SSRS 2008 R2 because following expressions works fine for padding and color but `"Me.Value"` doesn't work for Text Align.

```
    Padding = 2pt, =IIF(Me.Value IS NOTHING , "2pt", "25pt"), 2pt, 2pt

    Color = IIF(Me.Value IS NOTHING,"RED","GREEN")
```

I am aware of SSRS 2008 and 2005 bug which has been fixed in R2 but there must be a reason why `"Me.Value"` doesn't work for Text Align in R2.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to try the following code:-

```
=iif(Me.Equals(nothing),"Center","Right")
```

What I don't understand is, if the value is null why would you want to align it. Just make the default alignment to "Right".